# Read JSON file from Azure Blob Storage using PowerShell script and write back to another file in blob storage

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I have following JSON file (product.json) stored in Azure Blob storage. Is it possible to write PowerShell script to read this file from blob storage make some changes and write back to another file.
The output file I would like where following changes should occur:

1. Replace all "_id" with "id"
2. Remove all "_rev" and their values.

**Product.json**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "9f4da9d6babeb9d411c896baa68c94c8",
    "_rev": "1-4259271795225df18768ab68baacc96c",
    "account_id": 692278,
    "limit": 10000,
    "products": [
      "Commodity",
      "InvestmentStock"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "cc4b59f585b8556a2bedca78294a0797",
    "_rev": "1-410e479257faba0457bd9b4816c4dc95",
    "account_id": 328304,
    "limit": 10000,
    "products": [
      "Derivatives",
      "InvestmentStock",
      "CurrencyService"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "d7e2a72963cff2760514ff772969ffe0",
    "_rev": "1-2ec6e2679eae13b76410c93f49c14c4a",
    "account_id": 674364,
    "limit": 10000,
    "products": [
      "InvestmentStock"
    ]
  }
]
```

The **outputfile.json** should be as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id": "9f4da9d6babeb9d411c896baa68c94c8",
    "account_id": 692278,
    "limit": 10000,
    "products": [
      "Commodity",
      "InvestmentStock"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "cc4b59f585b8556a2bedca78294a0797",
    "account_id": 328304,
    "limit": 10000,
    "products": [
      "Derivatives",
      "InvestmentStock",
      "CurrencyService"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "d7e2a72963cff2760514ff772969ffe0",
    "account_id": 674364,
    "limit": 10000,
    "products": [
      "InvestmentStock"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you have tried so far (PS script that you have written) and what are the issues you're running into.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. Please edited version.

Comment: What version of SDK you're using. Also this is C# code. You mentioned PowerShell.

Comment: SDK 3.0. I was trying C#. But ask was PowerShell if possible. no idea its doable using PowerShell

Comment: I removed C# code which I tried. Lets not confuse other as ask was using PowerShell if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store the file in memory, you can use the `DownloadText()` method to download the content into memory.

The sample code:

```
$accountName = "xxx"
$accountKey = "xxx"
$containerName = "xxx"
$blobName = "Product.json"
$outputBlobName = "Output.json"    

$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey
$container_client = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $context
$source_blob_client = $container_client.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($blobName)

#download the blob as text into memory
$download_file = $source_blob_client.DownloadText()

$jsonContent = $download_file | ConvertFrom-Json

#Loop through json content and manipulate it
For ($i=0; $i -lt $jsonContent.Length; $i++) {
    $jsonContent[$i] | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "id" -NotePropertyValue $jsonContent[$i]._id
    $jsonContent[$i].PsObject.Properties.Remove("_id")
    $jsonContent[$i].PsObject.Properties.Remove("_rev")
}

$replaced_json = $jsonContent | ConvertTo-Json

#upload the json file
$dest_blob_client =  $container_client.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($outputBlobName)
$dest_blob_client.Properties.ContentType = "application/json"
$dest_blob_client.UploadText($replaced_json)

Write-Output("**completed**")
```

Comment: Not to mention but do not forget to pass the encoding type if the content in the file follows any specific encoding format. I have a file in unicode format and the simple DownloadText() would return me the text with extra spaces in each of the character.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant way, but this should do the trick:

```
$accountName = "account-name"
$accountKey = "account-key"
$containerName = "container-name"
$blobName = "Product.json"
$outputBlobName = "Output.json"

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey

#Read blob and save it to local file
Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob $blobName -Container $containerName -Destination "Product.json" -Context $ctx

#Read local file and get JSON object
$jsonContent = Get-Content -Raw -Path "Product.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

#Loop through json content and manipulate it
For ($i=0; $i -lt $jsonContent.Length; $i++) {
    $jsonContent[$i] | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "id" -NotePropertyValue $jsonContent[$i]._id
    $jsonContent[$i].PsObject.Properties.Remove("_id")
    $jsonContent[$i].PsObject.Properties.Remove("_rev")
}
$jsonContent

#Write content back to local disk
$jsonContent | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path $outputBlobName

#Upload into Azure Storage
$properties = @{"ContentType" = "application/json"}
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File $outputBlobName -Container $containerName -Blob $outputBlobName -Properties $properties -Context $ctx
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. Not sure whether its possible to store file in memory rather than local disk