# Read JSON from Azure Blob Storage using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage-account

I have a following JSON file/blob in the Azure Storage as students.json. Using Powershell, I want to read the contents of the file, student's FirstName and LastName where the MainSubject is Math

```html
{
  "college": {
    "students": [
      {
        "FirstName": "abc",
        "LastName": "xyz",
        "MainSubject": "Computers"
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "lmn",
        "LastName": "opq"
        "MainSubject": "Math"        
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question about a code of yours that isnt working regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results  as below and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragecontainer?view=azps-9.1.0) and Thanks to @ Ivan Yang's [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66651732) :

```
    $accountName = "rithwikstor"
    $accountKey = "XX"
    $containerName = "rithwik"
    $blobName = "emo.json"
    $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey
    $container_client = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $context
    $source_blob_client = $container_client.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($blobName)
    $download_file = $source_blob_client.DownloadText()
    $jsonContent = $download_file | ConvertFrom-Json
    
    
    $ans=$jsonContent.college | ConvertTo-json
    $res= $ans | ConvertFrom-json
    $res.students | where{$_.Mainsubject -eq 'Math'}
    $emo=$res.students | where{$_.Mainsubject -eq 'Math'}
    $emo | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty MainSubject
```

XX is the Storage account key. Got it from below:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to achieve the results without downloading the file?

Comment: @EZR, This is the way how I do it and I don't think there is any other way ,if there any i would like to know it.